# What is the best PHP method/class for cleaning strings to UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I've been using a couple of methods on a simple class, which have worked ok for me, but I've noticed that they are really slow due to `strtr()` and having a ton of translations defined.  Also it is really long and thus, more difficult to maintain and understand.

That said, all of the "bad" examples are solutions to real-world issues which have come up, translating strings into UTF8.

Can anyone tell me of there's a well known or more efficient means of doing this?  (yes, I've tried the `htmlentities()` methods and the `iconv()`methods but neither really replaced all the funky characters correctly.

Here's the class I'm using currently:
https://gist.github.com/2559140

Comment: What encoding are you coming *from*?

Comment: I'm not sure there _is_ a better way than what you're doing since you're not just character encoding you're actually translating the characters - actually transforming things like `Â` to `A` rather than using utf-8 from start to finish (which would mean you'd not need to translate the characters at all and you could quite happily leave `Â` in the source).

Comment: Indeed - we are coming from anything - as our users can upload documents and we pull from other sources... for the most part we've gotten things in in `iso-8859-1` and `windows-1251` - but it's not just letters, we've got crazy middot characters and the like too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mbstring support is now enabled (but not loaded) by default as of PHP 5.4.0. Loading the extension, this lets you do:

```
<? //PHP 5.4+
$ensureIsUTF8 = static function($data){
    $dataEncoding = \mb_detect_encoding(
        $data,
        ['UTF-8', 'windows-1251', 'iso-8859-1', /*others you encounter*/],
        true
    );

    //UTF-16/32 encoding detection always fails for PHP <= 5.4.1
    //Use detection code copied from PHP docs comments:
    //http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php
    if ($dataEncoding === false){

        $UTF32_BIG_ENDIAN_BOM = chr(0x00) . chr(0x00) . chr(0xFE) . chr(0xFF);
        $UTF32_LITTLE_ENDIAN_BOM = chr(0xFF) . chr(0xFE) . chr(0x00) . chr(0x00);
        $UTF16_BIG_ENDIAN_BOM = chr(0xFE) . chr(0xFF);
        $UTF16_LITTLE_ENDIAN_BOM = chr(0xFF) . chr(0xFE);

        $first2 = \substr($data, 0, 2);
        $first4 = \substr($data, 0, 4);

        if ($first4 === $UTF32_BIG_ENDIAN_BOM) {
            $dataEncoding = 'UTF-32BE';
        } elseif ($first4 === $UTF32_LITTLE_ENDIAN_BOM) {
            $dataEncoding = 'UTF-32LE';
        } elseif ($first2 === $UTF16_BIG_ENDIAN_BOM) {
            $dataEncoding = 'UTF-16BE';
        } elseif ($first2 === $UTF16_LITTLE_ENDIAN_BOM) {
            $dataEncoding = 'UTF-16LE';
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Whoa! No idea what that was.');
        }
    }

    if ($dataEncoding === 'UTF-8'){
        return $data;
    } else {
        return \mb_convert_encoding(
           $data,
           'UTF-8',
           $dataEncoding
        );      
    }
};

$utf8Data = $ensureIsUTF8(\file_get_contents('something'));
$utf8Data = $ensureIsUTF8(\file_get_contents('http://somethingElse'));
$utf8Data = $ensureIsUTF8($userProvidedData);
?>
```

Comment: that looks sexy... have not yet tried it, but I like the looks of it.